# Formatting text in checklists in Trello, or embedding comments

Tags: trello, formatting

How do I format text in a checklist, or embed comments, within a single checklist item in Trello?

I would like to provide additional notes and a hyperlink for several items in a checklist, but I can't find a good way to do so so that it applies to the individual checklist item and not the entire card.  Typing in the checklist item is just entered as one long stream.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 _
|_| Complete Software Installation
      Follow the instructions at www.example.com to complete the installation. 
      Please contact Bob when this is finished for next steps.
 _
|_| Schedule Software Training
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a way to format checklist items.

Comment: Will this be going on the dev board?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_` in place of `*`

With this you can make italic text, bold text, and italic+bold text.

There might be more formatting options, these are all I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the usual markdown options within your checklist items (full details on [Trello formatting options here](https://www.bluecatreports.com/blog/trello-formatting/)).

For what you are trying to achieve

```
 _
|_| Complete Software Installation
      Follow the instructions at www.example.com to complete the installation. 
      Please contact Bob when this is finished for next steps.
 _
|_| Schedule Software Training
```

I would format it like this

```
**Complete Software Installation**
- Follow the instructions at www.example.com to complete the installation. 
- Please contact Bob when this is finished for next steps.
**Schedule Software Training**
```

Literally copying and pasting that into a check list in Trello will create 4 checklist items. The first and last will be bolded which makes them look like top-level check list items. The 2nd and 3rd will be indented as bullet points for the first item.

ie

☐ **Complete Software Installation**

☐ • Follow the instructions at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to complete the installation.

☐ • Please contact Bob when this is finished for next steps.

☐ **Schedule Software Training**

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays there is some formatting you can do.

Summary explanation:
http://blog.trello.com/emoji-and-markdown-everywhere/

Complete syntax:
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax